# Bookmarklet containing a button

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that, when clicked, displays a search panel (i.e. a text input and button) on the page. In the text input one can enter a dom element Id and after clicking the search button, it will find the first element matching the Id entered into the search field. My problem is that I don't know how to add an `onclick` attribute to the button and then successfully call the corresponding function. Here's my code:

```
javascript:(
    function(){

        var disIPanel = document.getElementById('disappearioPanel');
        if(!disIPanel) {
            disIPanel = document.createElement('div');
            disIPanel.setAttribute('id', 'disappearioPanel');

            var disITxt = document.createElement('input');
            disITxt.setAttribute('type','text');
            disITxt.setAttribute('id', 'disappearioText');

            var disSBtn = document.createElement('button');
            disSBtn.innerHTML = 'Search';
            disSBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            // Here I add my 'onclick' attribute, if this is not the best way to go 
            // about it, please let me know
            disSBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'doThing()');

            disIPanel.appendChild(disITxt);
            disIPanel.appendChild(disSBtn);

            document.body.appendChild(disIPanel);
        } else {
            disIPanel.parentNode.removeChild(disIPanel);
        }
        // Here I've tried `function doThing() {...}` and `var doThing = function() {...}`
        // But neither ways of declaring/calling my function works
    }
    // Here I've tried `function doThing() {...}` and `var doThing = function() {...}`
    // But neither ways of declaring/calling my function works
)();
```

**Questions**

1. How/Where do I declare the function that I'm trying to call when clicking the button.
2. Can the `onclick` attribute actually call any function the way it currently is and, if not, how do I go about calling my function?

**Currently**

1. The bookmarklet successfully displays the search panel when called so there's no issue there
2. When I declare the function immediately after the `if` statement and then click the `Search` button, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: doThing is not defined`
3. When I declare the function outside the wrapper function, I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`

Comment: Maybe you should write a browser extension instead of a bookmarklet for something this complicated.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd like to see how far bookmarklets can get me xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions called from `onclick` attributes have to be in the global scope. All the code in your bookmarklet is in the scope of your IIFE. You could make it a global name with:

```
window.doThing = function() {
    ...
};
```

Or you can define the function normally, and use `addEventListener` instead of the `onclick` attribute:

```
disSBtn.addEventListener("click", doThing);
```

Comment: Eeeey! You're a boss, the `addEventListener` ended up working for me. Thanks!